# Ruby/Rails, Gate clause syntax to enforce security policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a difficult problem to solve.

I would like to replicate, the `title_with_if_statement` methods results, but using the syntax used in the `title` method. However, I do not know what to put in the `enforce_policy_to_level()` method to accomplish this.

I can do 'title_less_readable', but I find the title method much more readable since the policy is right at the top, and since I will be doing this for hundreds of methods, I want to keep it DRY and readable.

Any advice?

Is this even possible? It's basically a before_action but uses the method's own results.

```
class Car

  def title
    enforce_policy_to_level(1)
   # Code that returns the "Car Title" string
   "Car Title"
  end

  def title_less_readable
    # Code that returns "Car Title" string
    content = "Car Title"
    return secure_text(content) unless authorized_to_level?(1)
    content
  end

  def title_with_if_statement
    # Code that returns the "Car Title" string
    content = "Car Title"
    if authorized_to_level?(1)
      content
    else
      secure_text(content)
    end
  end

  private

  def enforce_policy_to_level(level)
    # Return from title method with the secured result of title method
    # if it's not authorized. In this example it would be secure_text('Car Title')
    # which output return '---------'
    # If if authorized, just continue with how title method would normally return
  end

  def authorized_to_level?(level)
    current_user_level = 1 # Dynamic from user record
    current_user_level >= level
  end

  def secure_text(text)
    'X' * text.length
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just something like this?

```
  def title
    enforce_policy_to_level(1) do
      "Car Title"
    end
  end

  private

  def enforce_policy_to_level(level, &block)
    if authorized_to_level?(level)
      secure_txt yield
    else
      yield
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating your concerns: I'd approach this by creating a separate function that handles the authorization.

```
module AuthorizedText
  module_function

  def secure_text(text, authorized)
    return authorized ? text : 'X' * text.length
  end
end
```

Call this in `Car` like this:

```
AuthorizedText.secure_text("Car Title", authorized_to_level(1))
```

You can shorthand this with a convenience method:

```
def secure(level, text)
  AuthorizedText.secure_text(text, authorized_to_level(level))
end
```

so that your `car_title` method would look like

```
def car_title
  secure(1, "Car Title")
end
```

You *could* generalize a method wrapper by defining a class method that would let you do something like

```
def car_title
  "Car Title"
end

secure :car_title
```

But I'd call this over-engineered and ultimately less readable to anyone who isn't you (including you 8 months from now, likely!). I'd avoid trying to be fancy like this, as fun as it may be.

Also, if `current_user` and `current_user_level` make sense outside the context of `Car` and you may want to reuse this elsewhere, you could go further by moving the auth checking methods into `AuthorizedText`, if that's appropriate:

```
module AuthorizedText
  module_function

  def secure_text(text, user, level = 0)
    return authorized?(user, level) ? text : 'X' * text.length
  end

  def authorized?(user, level)
    # for example; I don't know what your user object looks like
    user.level >= level
  end
end
```